# Calculating a chromatic polynomial that contains several identical subgraphs.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

So I learned about the theorem that states that if a graph $G$ has two subgraphs $X$ and $Y$ such that $X \cup Y = G$ and $X\cap  Y=K_n$, where $K_n$ is an $n$-clique, then the chromatic polynomial of $G$ is given by $$cr(G)=\frac{cr(X)cr(Y)}{cr(K_N)}$$Can this theorem be generalized so that instead of $K_n$ we have a graph $A$ and instead of $X$ and $Y$ we have a family of graphs $\mathcal X=\{X\subseteq G:\forall_{Y\subseteq G\setminus\{X\}} X\cap Y=A\}$, and the chromatic polynomial of G is given by $$cr(G)=\frac{1}{cr(A)}\prod_{X\in \mathcal X}cr(X)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some restricted cases when it works, e.g. if $X$ and $Y$ are both trees, but not in general.

Suppose a $k$-coloring of $X$ is possible, and we list all $\mathrm{cr}_k(X)$ distinct $k$-colorings of $X$.  By permuting the $k$ colors, we find that each possible $k$-coloring of its $n$-clique occurs exactly
$$\frac{\mathrm{cr}_k(X)}{k(k-1)\cdots(k-n+1)}=\frac{\mathrm{cr}_k(X)}{\mathrm{cr}_k(K_n)}$$
times.

This special property does not hold for any subgraph $A$ other than $K_n$: if an $n$-vertex graph has a non-edge, then there are ways to color it with $n$ colors, and there are ways to color it with $n-1$ colors.  So if we again list of $k$-colorings of $X$ (where $k \geq n$), some $k$-colorings of its subgraph $A$ will occur fewer times than others.

As a concrete counterexample, let's glue $C_6$ and $C_7$ along a $5$-vertex path $P_5$, and count $3$-colorings (the chromatic polynomials of these graphs are well known; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial)).

[image]

- $P_5$ has $48$ distinct $3$-colorings.
- $C_6$ has $66$ distinct $3$-colorings.
- $C_7$ has $126$ distinct $3$-colorings.

But we find $66 \times 126/48$ is not even an integer, so $\mathrm{cr}(C_6)\mathrm{cr}(C_7)/\mathrm{cr}(P_4)$ is not the chromatic polynomial of any graph (since we get a non-integer when we evaluate it at $3$).

(Note: there's no squared in the denominator in the formula.)

Comment: Thanks, I edited the denominator to remove the square. Also, is the generalization for the family of graphs true if we do consider $A$ to be a clique?

Comment: If A is a clique, then you can use the first formula recursively. You get a different denominator to the proposed generalization though.